# Esticar um elemento div em toda a extensão da tabela

Tags: html, css, tabela-html

Tenho uma tabela com muitas colunas que saem da tela do ecrã. Por cima desta tabela tenho um `div` com um `h2`. Não estou a conseguir que o `div` se expanda para além da tela do ecrã de modo a cobrir toda a largura da tabela. Exemplo, para melhor demonstrar a situação: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vax60nmz/2/)
Eu sei que se colocar o titulo como se fosse uma linha da tabela, ficaria do modo como quereria, mas pretendo utilizar um `div`, para o código ficar melhor organizado. Alguém me pode ajudar.

Exemplo:

```css
.colorir{
    padding: 5px;
    background: #003686;
    color: white;
```

```html
<div class="colorir">
 <h2>Este é o titulo que pretendo esticar até ao fim da tabela</h2>
</div>
<br>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
      <th>Four</th>
      <th>Five</th>
      <th>Six</th>
      <th>Seven</th>
      <th>Eight</th>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
      <th>Four</th>
      <th>Five</th>
      <th>Six</th>
      <th>Seven</th>
      <th>Eight</th>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
      <th>Four</th>
      <th>Five</th>
      <th>Six</th>
      <th>Seven</th>
      <th>Eight</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Eight</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Eight</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Eight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Eight</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Eight</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Eight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Eight</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Eight</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Eight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Eight</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Eight</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Eight</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o elemento `caption` para envolver a `div`.

Seguindo a sugestão do @GuilhermeNascimento, pode fazer assim :

```html
<table>
    <caption style="background-color:#003686; height:77px;color:white; text-align:left; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div>
            <h2>Este é o titulo que pretendo esticar até ao fim da tabela</h2>
        </div>
    </caption><br>
    <thead>
     <tr>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
            <th>Three</th>
            <th>Four</th>
            <th>Five</th>
            <th>Six</th>
            <th>Seven</th>
            <th>Eight</th>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
            <th>Three</th>
            <th>Four</th>
            <th>Five</th>
            <th>Six</th>
            <th>Seven</th>
            <th>Eight</th>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
            <th>Three</th>
            <th>Four</th>
            <th>Five</th>
            <th>Six</th>
            <th>Seven</th>
            <th>Eight</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
    <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Queria que área azul estica-se para a direita e em toda a largura da tabela e não para baixo. Tentei com `width:auto`, mas não funcionou.

Comment: desculpa, mas não poderei colocar o visto verde, pois, o que pretendo é mesmo sem ser na `página toda`. Numa janela mais pequena como faço para aparecer em toda a largura à medida que desloco-me para a direita. Não se me fiz entender. Eu vi que funciona na página com uma resolução maior e numa menor como fazer?

Comment: É para uma situação de visualizar num pequeno dispositivo, como iPhone. A tabela sai fora da lateral do ecrã, já o div não. Fica estático à largura inicial do ecrã.

Comment: @LuísAlves hoje é dia...Acho que consegui uma solução, com a sugestão de um amigo...

Comment: Desculpa a confusão é que estou aprendendo também...